# HMAC protected API and Postman request

Tags: postman, hmac, httpie

I am trying to issue requests against an API which is HMAC protected.

I can successfully send a request using a HMAC auth plugin for HTTPie like this:

```
http --auth-type=hmackey --auth="key1:secret1" api_url
```

However, I've not had any success by issuing requests through Postman. I'm following the link below which explains how to use a pre-request script, but I'm always getting a 401:

https://github.com/acquia/http-hmac-postman

Any thoguhts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a hmac for the post request and set it to the header, simply use cryptoJs as below in the pre-request script.

```
const secret = 'your_secret';

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(pm.request.body.toString(), secret);
var hashBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

console.log(hashBase64);

//set it to the environment variable
pm.environment.set("HmacContentSha", "hashBase64");
```

The environment variable `HmacContentSha` need to pass in the request header.

Comment: I also need to set the access key/api key and the hmac realm, don't I?

Comment: Yeah, it depends upon api requirement.